# Infinite looping in Django view

Tags: python, django

I am writing an application for time_slot in python

please look at this code

```
from datetime import datetime ,timedelta
appointments = [(datetime(2012, 5, 22, 10), datetime(2012, 5, 22, 10, 30)),

                    (datetime(2012, 5, 22, 12), datetime(2012, 5, 22, 13)),

                    (datetime(2012, 5, 22, 15, 30), datetime(2012, 5, 22, 17, 10))]

hours = (datetime(2012, 5, 22, 9), datetime(2012, 5, 24, 18))
duration = timedelta(minutes = 120)
def get_slots(hours, appointments,duration):

    slots = sorted([(hours[0], hours[0])] + appointments + [(hours[1], hours[1])])

    for start, end in ((slots[i][1], slots[i+1][0]) for i in range(len(slots)-1)):

        assert start <= end, "Cannot attend all appointments"

        while start + duration <= end:
            dt_obj = start
            date_str = dt_obj.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")


            today18 = start.replace(hour=17, minute=59, second=59, microsecond=0)

            if start <  today18:
               print "{:%d:%H:%M} - {:%d:%H:%M}".format(start, start + duration)

               start += duration
            else:
               start += timedelta(hours = 15)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    get_slots(hours, appointments,duration)
```

The above code is working fine for me when i am running it like python time_slots.py

But when i am using above code in djanog view like

```
from datetime importdatetime ,timedelta 
    duration = timedelta(minutes = 60)
    appointments = [(datetime(2012, 5, 22, 10), datetime(2012, 5, 22, 10, 30)),

                (datetime(2012, 5, 22, 12), datetime(2012, 5, 22, 13)),

                (datetime(2012, 5, 22, 15, 30), datetime(2012, 5, 22, 17, 10))]


   # hours = (datetime.datetime(2012, 5, 24, 18), datetime.datetime(2012, 5, 22, 9))
    hours = (datetime(2012, 5, 22, 9), datetime(2012, 5, 24, 18))
    slots = sorted([(hours[0], hours[0])] + appointments + [(hours[1], hours[1])])
    for start, end in ((slots[i][1], slots[i+1][0]) for i in range(len(slots)-1)):

        assert start <= end, "Cannot attend all appointments"

        while start + duration <= end:

            today18 = start.replace(hour=17, minute=59, second=59, microsecond=0)

            if start <  today18:

               print "{:%H:%M} - {:%H:%M}".format(start, start + duration)

            else:
               start += timedelta(hours = 15)
```

and when i am calling this view it's returning an infinite loop in console

Please help me what i am doing wrong here  i want the available time slots as i am getting in time_slots.py

Comment: In your second piece of code, you haven't defined `duration` - is that the problem?

Comment: i AM  pasing duration also will update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Django view, you have forgotten to add duration to start in the `if start < today18` clause.